# Login fields not properly aligned inside modal in semantic ui

Tags: jquery, html, semantic-ui

I am a beginner in Semantic UI and trying to develop a login form. I want login form in modal, but the login fields are not getting aligned properly and the modal dialog size is very large. Please suggest fixes to improve look of the login form.

```
HTML code:-
<a class="item agenda-item" id="test">  
    <span class="side-agenda-item"> <i class="bug icon"></i> File a Bug</span>
    <div class="ui modal test">
       <div class="ui input">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail address">
       </div>
       <br>
        <div class="ui input">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <br>
        <button class="ui primary button">Login</button>
      <br>
    </div>
  </a>

<script>
    $(function(){
      $("#test").click(function(){
        $(".test").modal('show');
      });
      $(".test").modal({
        closable: true
      });
    });
      </script>
```

Current login form:

[image: Current login form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CSS should fix the problem.

```
div.ui.input {
   width: 100%;
}
div.ui.input input {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Semantic-UI , it's recommended to style your login form with the built-in CSS , Here a simple example of login form :

[[LIVE DEMO]](https://codepen.io/SaadRegal/pen/PKXLYN)

**HTML**

```
<!--button-->
<a class="ui button primary" id="test"> 
Login </a>
<!--button-->

<!--modal-->
<div class="ui modal test">
    <div class="ui middle aligned center aligned grid">
        <div class="column">
            <h2 class="ui blue image header">
                <img src="assets/images/logo.png" class="image">
                <div class="content">
                    Log-in to your account
                </div>
            </h2>
            <form class="ui large form">
                <div class="ui  segment">
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="ui left icon input">
                            <i class="user icon"></i>
                            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail address">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="ui left icon input">
                            <i class="lock icon"></i>
                            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui fluid large primary submit button">Login</div>
                </div>
            </form>

            <div class="ui message">
                New to us? <a href="#">Sign Up</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--modal-->
```

**JS** *(same as yours)*

```
$(function(){
  $("#test").click(function(){
    $(".test").modal('show');
  });
  $(".test").modal({
    closable: true
  });
});
```

Comment: Better solution !